# Layout using tailwind Didn't get the desired value

Tags: css, reactjs, layout, tailwind-css

shape you want..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrzpI.png)
the current shape is...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cX8U4.png)

bar : h-14
nav : h-full
content : h-full
footer : h-14

I want a layout like that using tailwind, but it's not working the way I want.
The source is below.....
 `export default function MainComp() { return ( <div className='h-screen grid grid-rows-3 grid-cols-2 gap-1'> <div class="border-2 border-red-700 col-span-2">web bar</div> <div class="border-2 border-blue-700 row-span-2">nav bar</div> <div class="border-2 border-lime-800">contents</div> <div class="border-2 border-yellow-600 h-14">footer</div> </div> ) }`
find a fixer...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Consider applying different grid row track sizings by applying a different value for `grid-template-rows`:

```js
function MainComp() {
  return (
    <div className='h-screen grid grid-rows-[auto_1fr_theme(spacing.14)] grid-cols-2 gap-1'>
      <div class="border-2 border-red-700 col-span-2">web bar</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-blue-700 row-span-2">nav bar</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-lime-800">contents</div>
      <div class="border-2 border-yellow-600">footer</div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<MainComp/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: <div class="border-2 border-blue-700 row-span-2 w-24">nav bar</div>
In this case, the phenomenon is the same
I need to use something other than grid.

Comment: I would say you should still use grid, but adapt the `grid-template-rows` as needed.